# Dates not shown correctly on X axis in line graph

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 2d array where the first array is a list of dates. The dates are in the format `#2020-05-18#` and there are 35 of them.

When constructing a graph with the dates as the X axis they don't show up as dates just numbers 1-35.

If I add the line `.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"` I get dates but totally wrong ones. They start at 1900-01-01 and continues with 1900-01-02 and so on all the way to 1900-02-04.
I've tried to change the array into a long, a double, a date but it doesn't help.

Anyone knows what's wrong?

This is the code:

```
Set myChart = Graf.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=20, Top:=53, Width:=1000, Height:=400)
    With myChart.Chart
        For i = 1 To UBound(AllDataLists, 2) 'AllDataLists is the 2d array. The first array contains the 
                                             'dates, the rest contains the data.

            ReDim ActualData(1 To UBound(AllDataLists, 1)) As Date

            For j = 1 To UBound(AllDataLists, 1)
                ActualData(j) = AllDataLists(j, i)
            Next j

            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(i).Values = ActualData
            .SeriesCollection(i).ChartType = xlLine
            .SeriesCollection(i).AxisGroup = 1
        Next i

        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    End With
```

Nevermind I solved it!!! This was the solution:

```
Set myChart = Graf.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=20, Top:=53, Width:=1000, Height:=400)
    With myChart.Chart
        For i = 1 To UBound(AllDataLists, 2)
            If i = 1 Then
                ReDim actualdate(1 To UBound(AllDataLists, 1)) As Date
                For j = 1 To UBound(AllDataLists, 1)
                    actualdate(j) = AllDataLists(j, i)
                Next j
            Else
                ReDim actualdata(1 To UBound(AllDataLists, 1)) As Integer
                For j = 1 To UBound(AllDataLists, 1)
                    actualdata(j) = AllDataLists(j, i)
                Next j
            End If

                .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            If i = 1 Then
                .SeriesCollection(i).XValues = actualdate
            Else
                
                .SeriesCollection(i).Values = actualdata
                .SeriesCollection(i).ChartType = xlLine
                .SeriesCollection(i).Name = NewDataLabel(i - 1)
            End If
            
            
            .SeriesCollection(i).AxisGroup = 1
            
            
        Next i
    End With
```

Basically I made two arrays, one with the dates and one with the data. Then I used the array with the dates as the `XValues` instead of `Values`.

Comment: What 'NewDataLabel' is? You do not show any declarations...

Comment: It's higher up in the code. The code shown is just the part concerning the question. Else it would be a really long question!

Answer (score 0):

I should have reloaded the page earlier ;-)

```
Sub AddChart()

    Dim myChart
    Set myChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=20, Top:=53, Width:=1000, Height:=400)
    
    With myChart.Chart

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "{43831,43862,43891,43922,43952}"
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "{-10,10,30,50,70}"
        .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "DD.MM.YYYY"
    End With
End Sub
```